# iOS core data one to many relationship NSSET

Tags: ios, core-data

I am just wondering if it is possible to use a custom class instead of NSSET for one to many relationships in core data?

For example lets say we have:

```
@interface Company : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *companyId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *companyName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSET *employees;

@end
```

I would like to create a class called employees like:

```
@interface Employees : NSSet

- (void) someCustomMethod;

@end
```

and then change the declaration of employees in Company to

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Employees *employees;
```

While it builds successfully it raises an exception when I try to access someCustomMethod of Employees. Probably because the object has been created as NSSET and not as Employees.

So my questions is, can I do this and if so how do I get employees to be created as Employees and not NSSET.

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that is possible. The Core Data accessor methods are dynamically generated
at runtime, and `NSSet` is used to represent a to-many relationship.

Note also that the [`NSSet` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) discourages you from subclassing:

> There should be little need of subclassing. If you need to customize
>   behavior, it is often better to consider composition instead of
>   subclassing.

and later:

> If the behavior you want to add supplements that of the existing
>   class, you could write a category on `NSSet`. Keep in mind, however,
>   that this category will be in effect for all instances of `NSSet` that
>   you use, and this might have unintended consequences. Alternatively,
>   you could use composition to achieve the desired behavior.

In your case, a category method on `Company` that operates on all the `employees`
*might* be the workaround.